# How to create this wordpress navbar menu from html template?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have html website template which I am trying to convert into wordpress theme. Everything is going fine, but now I ran into a problem. I am trying to create a navbar menu. It isn't hard task if menu is simple, but this particular one is hard to accomplish for me.

The html of this navbar menu is follwing:

```
<div class="art-nav">
    <div class="art-nav-l"></div>
    <div class="art-nav-r"></div>
<div class="art-nav-outer">
<div class="art-nav-wrapper">
<div class="art-nav-inner">
    <ul class="art-hmenu">
        <li>
            <a href="./new-page.html" class="active"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">New Page</span></a>
        </li>   
        <li>
            <a href="./new-page-2.html"><span class="l"></span><span class="r"></span><span class="t">New Page 2</span></a>
        </li>   
    </ul>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Which i tried to do:

```
<div class="art-nav">
    <div class="art-nav-l"></div>
    <div class="art-nav-r"></div>
<div class="art-nav-outer">
<div class="art-nav-wrapper">
<div class="art-nav-inner">
    <nav class="site-menu">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
    </nav>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then I changed the css too and gave .site-menu the properties which previously belonged to .art-menu, but it did not work, my menu does not look like it needs to. There are so many wrappers around this menu and css of this menu is very very long. So everything is very confusing for me as I am a beginner. How should I format my code to create a menu which looks like the one in html? If someone wants to see the css file, then I will send it. Also if someone needs more information for answering, I will send it.

Comment: You can't build a separate menu with divs and have it translate to WordPress. Wordpress builds its menu as follows. .menu > ul >li > ul > li etc. where is your CSS

Comment: My CSS:

http://expirebox.com/download/fb008b1485574f73a69d091abfc95781.html

Comment: Thanks for comment Justin Medas ,could you give me some hints how to make this code to wordpress menu, because i have to do it, one way or another. Your first comment doesn't really help me much as I am beginner. I could send more html code of project if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The menu's css declarations probably include outer wrapping elements. Just changing one inner menu wrapper is not enough, you'd have to comb through the entire css to see what else you need to copy.

A simpler solution would be to keep the html template's classes intact and modify the `wp_nav_menu` arguments.

```
$menu_args = array(
    'container'       => false,
    'menu_class'      => 'art-hmenu',
);

wp_nav_menu( $menu_args );
```

For more details, check out the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

You must use Wordpress menu walker. For example:

```
class Walker_Quickstart_Menu extends Walker {

    // Tell Walker where to inherit it's parent and id values
    var $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 
        'id'     => 'db_id' 
    );

    /**
     * At the start of each element, output a <li> and <a> tag structure.
     * 
     * Note: Menu objects include url and title properties, so we will use those.
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $output .= sprintf( "\n<li><a href='%s'%s>%s</a></li>\n",
            $item->url,
            ( $item->object_id === get_the_ID() ) ? ' class="current"' : '',
            $item->title
        );
    }

}
```

And details in here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker